# How to get unique values from list using previous/current/next?

Tags: python, stack, yield

I have implemented a program which takes a list, and returns unique values based on the previous, current and next elements.

However, the program does not work when the list has more than two of the same element in the beginning.

Ex: `[0, 0, 0, 1]`

Here is the code, followed by a description of the mechanics.

```
def test(current):
    
    iterator = iter(current)
    previous_item = next(iterator)
    current_item = next(iterator)
    next_item = True
    
    
    while next_item:
        
        try:
            next_item = next(iterator)       
        except StopIteration:
            next_item = None      
        
        if previous_item == current_item:
            current_item = next_item

        else:
            yield previous_item
            previous_item = current_item
            current_item = next_item

        
    if previous_item:
        yield previous_item


        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    l = [0, 0, 1, 2]
    
    for u in test(l):
        print(u)
```

The loop terminates if `next_item` is `None`. I only yield a `previous_item` if `previous_item` is not equal to `current_item`. I also only move the `previous_item` "pointer" if `previous_item` is not equal to `current_item`. `previous_item` is always guaranteed to have a value, so I am confused why inputs such as `[0, 0, 0, 1]` do not yield anything.

Regards,

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I get people telling me I post too much code, and people telling me I post too little. To each his own.

Comment: Posting just the right amount of code to illustrate the problem you encountered is a delicate balancing act. It's easy to post too much code and hide the problem entirely. For some tips on creating a minimal example that recreates the problem, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is testing whether `next_item` is [not null](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans), meaning not equal to `0`, `None`, `[]`, `{}`, etc... So once the value take 0, the loop stops.

Instead you could do:

```
def test(current):
    
    iterator = iter(current)
    previous_item = next(iterator)
    current_item = next(iterator)
    next_item = 0
    
    
    while next_item is not None:
        
        try:
            next_item = next(iterator)       
        except StopIteration:
            next_item = None      
        
        if previous_item == current_item:
            current_item = next_item

        else:
            yield previous_item
            previous_item = current_item
            current_item = next_item

        
    if previous_item:
        yield previous_item
```

Comment: How does this fix the problem? `while next_item:` and `while next_item is not None:` will both terminate the loop when `next_item` becomes `None`.

Comment: Sure, but when `next_item` takes the value 0, it will also stop the loop, hence the early termination in this case